# Finding the lowest value within an instance variable

Tags: python-3.x

```
class ShoppingCart:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cart = []

    def add_item(self, item):
        """ (ShoppingCart, Item) -> NoneType
        Adds an item to the cart.
        """
        self.cart.append(item)

    def show_cheapest_item(self):
        """ (ShoppingCart) -> int
        Return the cheapest item in the cart, or -1 if no items are in the cart
        """
        # my point of confusion
```

---

```
class Item:

    """ An instance of an item """
    def __init__(self, price):
        """ (Item, float)
        Initialize an Item
        """
        self.price = price
```

I am trying to return the cheapest item in the cart, however, I am unable to access the price list in any way.

Comment: Please post the full code of both classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def show_cheapest_item(self):
    """ (ShoppingCart) -> int
    Return the cheapest item in the cart, or -1 if no items are in the cart
    """
    if len(self.cart) == 0:
        return -1
    cheapest_item = self.cart[0]
    for item in self.cart[1:]:
        if item.price < cheapest_item.price:
            cheapest_item = item
    return cheapest_item
```

Comment: I wouldn't return -1 here.. if there's nothing in the cart the cheapest item is 0.

Comment: Neither would I, but that's what the description of the method in the original question said.

Comment: Be interesting if someone entered an item price of -1... :) (but yeah - it's what the OP has stated :p)

Answer (score 0):

```
class ShoppingCart:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cart = []

    def add_item(self, item):
       """ (ShoppingCart, Item) -> NoneType
       Adds an item to the cart.
       """
       self.cart.append(item)

    def show_cheapest_item(self):
       """ (ShoppingCart) -> int
       Return the cheapest item in the cart, or -1 if no items are in the cart
       """
       return -1 if len(self.cart) == 0 else min(self.cart)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [min](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) and [operator.attrgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter)

```
import operator

def show_cheapest_item(self):
    """ (ShoppingCart) -> int
    Return the cheapest item in the cart, or -1 if no items are in the cart
    """
    return -1 if not self.cart else min(self.cart, key=operator.attrgetter('price'))
```